# Cannot get date from bootstrap WTForm

Tags: python, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, flask-wtforms

I am using WTForm and bootstrap to get the date from a user. The page loads fine with the form to enter a date. I can click on a date. Hit submit but the my print(form.dmrDate.data) returns None.

I think the problem is an inconsistency between my bootstrap and WTForms date formats, here is the latest iteration leveraging datetimepicker. Datetimepicker seems to be a popular for getting date but I'm open to alternatives. Any ideas what I’m doing wrong?

Also, I want the date in %m/%d/%Y.

Routes.py

```
from flask import url_for, redirect
from dmrApp.models import Restaurants
from dmrApp.forms import DashboardForm

@app.route('/dashboard', methods=["GET","POST"])
def dashboard():
    form=DashboardForm()
    restaurants = Restaurants.query.with_entities(Restaurants.name).all()
    print(form.dmrDate.data)
    return render_template('dashboard.html', title='Dashboard', form=form, restaurants=restaurants)
```

Forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import DateField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

class DashboardForm(FlaskForm):
    restaurant = QuerySelectField(query_factory=choice_query, allow_blank=True,
                                  validators=[DataRequired()], get_label='name')
    dmrDate = DateField('date', validators=[DataRequired()], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

My html/bootstrap:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group row">
                Select date:
                {{ form.dmrDate(class="form-control form-control-lg", type="date") }}
                {% if form.dmrDate.errors %}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.dmrDate.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

java for datapicker

```
<script>
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you you haven't linked Datetimepicker to any HTML element.

Fix: add the `.datepicker` class to `form.dmrDate(class="")` like so

```py
{{ form.dmrDate(class="form-control form-control-lg datepicker", type="date") }}
```